# Android studio keeps asking to upgrade Gradle when importing sample projects

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

Downloaded AndroidStudio for Windows and importing sample projects from within the AndroidStudio GUI.

Everytime I import a project, it asks me to upgrade Gradle

> To take advantage of all the latest features (such as Instant Run),
>   improvements and security fixes, we strongly recommend that you update
>   the Android Gradle plugin to version 2.3.0 and Gradle to version 3.3. 
>   You can learn more about this version of the plugin from the release
>   notes.

Is this normal?

AndroidStudio 2.3

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is normal if the projects you are importing are more than a few weeks old.  The latest version of Android Studio and Gradle are pretty new at this point, so it will ask you to update older projects.

Comment: When it asks me to update gradle, am I actually downloading something new or merely changing a config file?

Comment: You are changing the android manifest, but it looks like Android Studio could be re-downloading grade with each project.  If you want to change that, here is some more insight, though I'm not sure how this works with future updates. https://teamtreehouse.com/community/why-is-gradle-downloaded-each-and-every-time-android-studio